# In .net3 wcf the wsdl output has a xmlns:i0 that is used in the wsdl:service wsdl:port binding where do I make changes so it uses my target namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl, .net-3.0

In .net3 wcf, the wsdl output has a xmlns:i0 that is used in the wsdl:service wsdl:port binding where do I make changes so it uses my target namespace (xmlns:tns) also the wsdl:binding element is missing what changes need to be made?

I've added namepsaces to all the wcf attributes that take a namespace in their constructors.

I have a feeling that they are both interlinked as the wsdl:binding is missing from my wsdl and the wsdl:port is

```
<wsdl:port name="aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.ddddd.HelloService" binding="i0:aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.ddddd.HelloService"/>
```

In the wsld:definations i have

```
... xmlns:tns="http://aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.ddddd" xmlns:i0="http://tempuri.org" ...
```

so how do I get rid of the xmlns:i0 and ensure that the binding in my port uses the same namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 15mins after posting

its the bindingNamespace in the endpoint configuration eg

> endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
>   **bindingNamespace="aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.ddddd"** name="aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.ddddd.HelloService"
>   contract="aaaaa.bbbbb.ccccc.ddddd.IHelloService"